# C: Printing a valid path through recursion

Tags: c, recursion, minimax

Desc.
I am making a game between two players that draw tokens. Player A always starts first. They have 5 options to pick: left, right, left + left + 1, left + right, right + right - 1
If they pick 2 in one turn, the next turn, they have to pick only 2.

Problem
It gives me the correct result, but I want to keep track of what turns were made. How do I save only the valid paths through recursion?

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    int score;
    int moves[MAX_SIZE];
    int turns;
} SCORE;

/**     Drawing tokens
 * this is a game where 2 AI opponens draw tokens (numbers)
 * Each player can either draw 2 cards, but then has to draw only one card the next turn
 * or can draw 1 card only
 * player with larger tokenSum wins
 * program uses minimax algorithm
 */

void getTokens(int* tokens, size_t* size) {

    int token;
    printf("Zetony:\n");
    while(scanf("%d", &token) == 1) {
        tokens[(*size)++] = token;
        if (*size > MAX_SIZE) {
            *size = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    //if (!feof(stdin) ) *size = 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**     A function to get the highest of 5 choices (playerA)
 * if player A can draw 2 cards
 * @returns max of 5
 */
int maxOfFive (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    int choices[] = {b, c, d, e};
    int max = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (choices[i] > max) {
            max = choices[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**     A function to get the lowest of 5 choices (playerB)
 * if playerB can draw 2 cards
 * @returns min of 5 ints
 */
int minOfFive (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    int choices[] = {b, c, d, e};
    int min = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (choices[i] < min) {
            min = choices[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * @returns max of 2 ints
 */
int max (int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * @returns min of 2 ints
 */
int min (int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int minimaxRec (int* tokens, int start, int end, int scoreA, bool maximize, bool twoA, bool twoB) {
    if (start > end) return scoreA; //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    if (maximize) {
        if(twoA && ( (end - start) >= 1) ) {
            int a = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 1, end, scoreA + tokens[start], !maximize, twoA, twoB );
            int b = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end - 1, scoreA + tokens[end], !maximize, twoA, twoB );
            int c = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 2, end, scoreA + tokens[start] + tokens[start + 1], !maximize, !twoA, twoB );
            int d = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end - 2, scoreA + tokens[end] + tokens[end - 1], !maximize, !twoA, twoB );
            int e = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 1, end - 1, scoreA + tokens[start] + tokens[end], !maximize, !twoA, twoB );
            printf("start:%d end:%d", start, end);
            return maxOfFive(a, b, c, d, e);
        }
        else {
            int a = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 1, end, scoreA + tokens[start], !maximize, !twoA, twoB );
            int b = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end - 1, scoreA + tokens[end], !maximize, !twoA, twoB );
            printf("start:%d end:%d", start, end);
            return max(a,b);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(twoB && ( (end - start) >= 1) ) {
            int a = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 1, end, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, twoB);
            int b = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end - 1, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, twoB);
            int c = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 2, end, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, !twoB);
            int d = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end - 2, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, !twoB);
            int e = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 1, end - 1, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, !twoB);
            return minOfFive(a, b, c, d, e);
        }
        else {
            int a = minimaxRec(tokens, start + 1, end, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, !twoB );
            int b = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end - 1, scoreA, !maximize, twoA, !twoB );
            return min(a, b);
        }
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SCORE minimax2 (int* tokens, int start, int end, bool maximize, int* turns) {
    SCORE result;
    if (start > end) {
        *turns = 0;
        return result;
    }
    SCORE l = minimax2(tokens, start + 1, end, !maximize, turns);
    SCORE r = minimax2(tokens, start, end - 1, !maximize, turns);

    if (maximize) {
        if (tokens[start] + l.score > tokens[end] + r.score) {
            result.score = tokens[start] + l.score;
            result.moves[*(turns)++] = start;
            return result;
        }
        else {
            result.score = tokens[end] + r.score;
            result.moves[*(turns)++] = end;
            return result;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (l.score < r.score) {
            result.score = l.score;
            result.moves[*(turns)++] = start;
            return result;
        }
        else {
            result.score = r.score;
            result.moves[*(turns)++] = end;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SCORE minimax (int* tokens, size_t size) {
    int start = 0, end = size - 1;
    bool maximize = true, twoA = true, twoB = true;
    SCORE result;
    result.score = 0;
    result.score = minimaxRec(tokens, start, end, result.score, maximize, twoA, twoB);
    return result;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {

    int tokens[MAX_SIZE], turns = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    SCORE result;
    getTokens(tokens, &size);
    if (!size) {
        printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    result = minimax(tokens, size);
    printf("\n%d\n", result.score);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried saving in into an array and got all tangled up.

Comment: What is "2"?  "left + left".   The answer, btw, is to pass a variable that you need to accumulate the values as you go.  You can also return the values you want to keep and keep track that of those in the caller.

Comment: `minimaxRec()` seems to have a lot of duplication.  Extract to functions and pass in what differs.

Comment: Upper case symbols (`SCORE`), by convention, are used for symbolic constants and enum values.

Comment: Avoid global variables.  `SCORE.turns` is not used.

Comment: `minimax2()`: The first `return result` returns an uninitialized value.

Comment: Consider creating a array version of `min()` and `max()` (or if you wan to to be fancy one function that takes a compare function) along the lines of `min(size_t n, int values[n])`.  Use an initializer to call the function `min(2, (int []) {a, b})`

Comment: What do you mean with "valid path"?

Comment: It seem to me that you could implement this as a BST. In which case you can give each node an unique id, then record which nodes that were visited.

Comment: @Lundin: why a BST and not a simple array acting as a queue?

Comment: No reaction from author. Voting to close.